# the immune system vs.natural defense

Tags: word-usage

Would you please explain, what's the difference between these words (if there's any)? Eg. in the sentence:

> Probiotics promote *the body's natural defenses*.
>
> Probiotics promote *the immune system.*

Which one is better / more common?

Thank you

Comment: I'm sure the human body has lot's of "natural defences" besides the immune system. But this is just advertising flim-flam, so accuracy is hardly relevant. To be honest, I'm not convinced this is a proper use of the verb ***promote***, either.

Comment: Whether it matches historical use of _promote_ or not, it is boilerplate (extremely common) usage now, especially in vague health claims on supplements.

Comment: @Adam: I can only read the construction in context for 2 of the 11 written instances of [*promote the immune system*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22promote+the+immune+system%22), and one of those is actually a reference to promoting *the immune system's **health*** (which I have no quarrel with). But I hear what you say - even though I can't help suspecting part of the motivation for using *promote* in such contexts is that it obscures the meaning just sufficiently that they might avoid being sued for making unsubstantiated claims about supposed medical benefits.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Re: _"part of the motivation....."_  Absolutely.  In fact, the FDA explicitly stares that _"that statements using the word **promote** can be appropriate when the statements do not suggest disease prevention or treatment or use for a serious health condition that consumers cannot evaluate"_  (Food and Drug Administration, 21 CFR Part 101 [Docket No. 98N-0044])  See also bullet C4 https://www.fda.gov/Food/GuidanceRegulation/GuidanceDocumentsRegulatoryInformation/DietarySupplements/ucm103340.htm

Comment: @Fumblefingers - Your _woo_ harvest might be greater searching the web than searching books:  https://www.google.com/#q=%22promote+the+body's%22+immune&*

Comment: @Adam: Sure - the usage *exists*. But the mere fact that it rattled *my* cage suggests it might not be a good idea to actually *promote* it. I'm not sure *exactly* what "equivalent text" could substitute for ***promote*** in OP's example (perhaps *because* of the deliberate obfuscation), but deciding what things can or can't be "promoted" looks like a veritable minefield to me (and probably no two people would agree on exactly the same list of such things).

Comment: Corks! I can't believe I write ***lot's*** in my first comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really, there is no difference, and both sentences say the same thing. "Immune system" is more formal, and more scientific, so if you were to write it in a scientific paper, you would be making a specific claim that probiotics do something to help the human immune system.

"Natural defenses" sounds like something you'd read on the side of a bottle from a health food store. In many cases, they may stick to vague terms to avoid laws against false advertising.

In my personal use I would probably stick to "immune system", but I would only write about probiotics if I had well-researched claims that I could then make to explain myself.